# How to get 'apple-touch-icon from URL?

Tags: ios, url, uiwebview, favicon, apple-touch-icon

I am developing an iOS app in which user can bookmark the websites and later they can view it by tapping `Apple-Touch-Icon` (Its completely similar to iOS safari app).

Here my question is how to get/parse the `Apple-Touch-Icon` from a URL? there are so many questions and answers to get `favicon` but I don't see any answer/tutorial to get `Apple-Touch-Icon`.

Can you someone please help me out on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i didn't get what exactly you want, need to show an .png file from server ?

Comment: If use iOS safari app, you might have seen this. Please open the safari app -> go to google.com -> tap add to bookmark -> you will be navigating to add to book mark screen where you can view google icon at left side. Here they have retrieved google icon from url I would  like to implement same feature

Answer (score 0):

There is a framework for iOS and MacOS called FavIcon that will make it work:

https://github.com/leonbreedt/FavIcon